# Using libreOffice Calc function in macro

Tags: worksheet-function, macros, libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

I am trying to create a basic macro function in calc to perform a hexadecimal to binary conversion with more then 10 bits. But I've got a lot of troubles.

First, where can I find actual documentation? I only found very little examples that didn't help much and the [BASIC guide](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/BASIC_Guide) is also quite succinct.

And mainly (if first doesn't respond to it), as you can see in the example below, I am trying to use `CONCATENATE` inside the macro. Which is a perfectly working function inside the spreadsheet. But I get the following error message:

```
Sub-procedure or function procedure not defined.
```

So, how to use such function inside the macro, is it even possible?

Here, is the code of my macro:

```
Function HEX2BINREAL(hexIn as string) as string

   n = len(hexIn)
   Dim binOut as string
   binOut = ""

   For i = 1 to n
      ActChar = Mid(hexIn,i,1)
      Select Case ActChar
        Case "0"
            binOut = CONCATENATE(binOut,"0000")
        Case "1"
            binOut = CONCATENATE(binOut,"0001")
        Case "2"
            binOut = CONCATENATE(binOut,"0010")
        Case "3"
            binOut = CONCATENATE(binOut,"0011")
        Case "4"
            binOut = CONCATENATE(binOut,"0100")
        Case "5"
            binOut = CONCATENATE(binOut,"0101")
        Case "6"
            binOut = CONCATENATE(binOut,"0110")
        Case "7"
            binOut = CONCATENATE(binOut,"0111")
        Case "8"
            binOut = CONCATENATE(binOut,"1000")
        Case "9"
            binOut = CONCATENATE(binOut,"1001")
        Case "a", "A"
            binOut = CONCATENATE(binOut,"1010")
        Case "b", "B"
            binOut = CONCATENATE(binOut,"1011")
        Case "c", "C"
            binOut = CONCATENATE(binOut,"1100")
        Case "d", "D"
            binOut = CONCATENATE(binOut,"1101")
        Case "e", "E"
            binOut = CONCATENATE(binOut,"1110")
        Case "f", "F"
            binOut = CONCATENATE(binOut,"1111")
        End Select
   next i
HEX2BINREAL = binOut
end Function
```

Thanks

Comment: I see that you give CONCATENATE in all caps in your text, but have it in proper case in your code sample.  Does it work in all-caps in the sheet?  Have you tried all-caps in your function?

Comment: case doesn't seem to be important, in the spreadsheet, it converts into maj automatically. Tried to replace by CONCATENATE, same result.

Comment: Does the BASIC subset they use have an `import` function?  If it does, you'll need to import the function definition of Concatenate into your function before you can use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The macro language does not have access to spreadsheet functions unless you spend several lines loading up the one you want.

For the purpose here, it would be much simpler to just use the Basic concatenate operator of `&`.  Like so:

```
Case "0"
    binOut = binOut & "0000"
```

Comment: Thank you, that solve my particular problem. Could you just go into more details about the use of spreadsheet functions within a macro?

Comment: Some functions are available through the API.  From the wiki: [Computing With Cell Ranges](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/BASIC_Guide/Editing_Spreadsheet_Documents#Computing_With_Cell_Ranges) and the [API documentation](https://www.openoffice.org/api/docs/common/ref/com/sun/star/sheet/XSheetOperation.html).  I'm not sure how to use spreadsheet operations not supported by `.computeFunction`

Comment: Also see [Andrew Pitonyak's macro document](http://www.pitonyak.org/oo.php) section  `6.28. Use FunctionAccess to call Calc Functions`.